# How to run multiple npm scripts on Heroku when deploying?

Tags: node.js, heroku

In my `package.json` I have the following scripts:

```
"scripts": {
    "api": "node ./api/index.js",
    "client": "node ./client/index.js",
    "start": "npm run client && npm run api"
  },
```

I'm trying to run `start` which kicks off both my client (react frontend) and api. In my `Procfile`, I have: `web: npm run start`. The Heroku build succeeds, but only the first script ever runs. Is there a way to run multiple npm scripts from my `Procfile` as soon as my app is deployed to Heroku?

Comment: Change the `&&` to `&`?

Comment: Is it working for you? I also have the same question.

Answer (score 0):

[Heroku multi dyno](https://help.heroku.com/CTFS2TJK/how-do-i-run-multiple-processes-on-a-dyno) this will help you
just enter `&` at end of each command and `wait -n` at end

Comment: That's not "multi dyno". It clearly says this runs "multiple processes on a dyno".